# Why does iOS 11.3.1 insist on reinstalling its defaults apps

Tags: ios

Since yesterday, my iOS 11.3.1 (on an iPhone SE) is in a strange, beforehand unseen state whereby most of its default apps apparently  have become uninstalled somehow (for instance, Maps and Videos are marked with the Cloud-like download item) and iOS proceeds with downloading them from somewhere (hopefully/presumably Apple) anew when I click on their icons (has e.g. happened with Notes and Podcast so far.)

I am wondering: Is this a known phenomenon? For what reason does iOS enter into such a state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called 'Offload Unused Apps' and was a feature introduced in iOS 11.

Source [OSX Daily](http://osxdaily.com/2017/10/07/enable-offload-unused-apps-ios/):

> If you frequently run out of storage space on an iPhone or iPad, you will appreciate a new feature in iOS that automatically saves storage for you. Called Offload Unused Apps, the toggle allows the iPhone or iPad to perform housekeeping and delete apps that have gone unused for a while, just as the name implies. Offloading used apps can noticeably help to reduce storage constraints on a device, since most of us have a handful of apps that may not be getting any usage but are taking up storage space on an iOS device anyway.

To change this setting:

1. Open `Settings`
2. Tap on `iTunes & App Store`
3. Scroll down to locate `Offload Unused Apps` and toggle to the desired position
   [image]
4. Exit out of `Settings`

If this is turned ON, iOS will automatically remove apps you don't use only when your storage is low.  To use that app again, as you've discovered, you just tap on the app and it will automatically download back to your device.

You’ll notice that while the feature will remove the app, **it will maintain data and documents related to the applications that are offloaded.**

Comment: Yep, that must be it. It's still surprising to me why it decided to offload e.g. Podcast (which I use daily).

Comment: You can just turn this feature off for a few weeks and see if it's better for your use.